# Class pattern is matching the wrong cases

Tags: python, serialization, isinstance, structural-pattern-matching

I'm writing an object serializer but am having issues where the [class patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id52) are not matching the expected cases:

```
def dump_obj(x):
    match(x):
        case list():
            emit('L')
            dump_obj(len(x))
            for elem in x:
                dump_obj(elem)
        case Iterable():
            emit('I')
            dump_obj((type(x), list(x)))
        case tuple():
            emit('T')
            dump_obj(list(x))
        case str():
            emit('S')
            dump_obj(len(x))
            emit(x)
        case int():
            emit('D')
            emit(str(x))
        case _:
            raise TypeError(f'Unknown obj {x!r}')
```

When I call *dump_obj()* with a tuple, it giving an infinite recursion on the I-case for iterables rather than matching the T-case for tuples.

When I call *dump_obj()* with a list subclass, it is matching the L-case for lists instead of the intended I-case for iterables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First problem:  Ordering

The cases are not independent of one another.  They are tested from the top-down (like a long if/elif chain) and the first to match wins.

In the example, the specific match tests like like *list*, *tuple*, and *str* need to come before more general matches like *Iterable*.  Otherwise with the current code, a tuple input like `(10, 20, 30)` will match the I-case instead of the intended T-case.

### Second problem:  Specificity

A class pattern performs an [*isinstance()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) check which would match both a type and subclasses of the type.  To restrict the case to an exact match, use a [type guard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id8):

```
case list() if type(x) == list:
    ...
```

### Putting it all together

With both solutions applied, here is the new code:

```
def dump_obj(x):
    match(x):
        case list() if type(x) == list:   # <-- Added guard
            emit('L')
            dump_obj(len(x))
            for elem in x:
                dump_obj(elem)
        case tuple() if type(x) == tuple: # <-- Added guard
            emit('T')
            dump_obj(list(x))
        case str() if type(x) == str:     # <-- Added guard
            emit('S')
            dump_obj(len(x))
            emit(x)
        case Iterable():                  # <-- Move after list, tuple, str
            emit('I')
            dump_obj((type(x).__name__, list(x)))
        case int():
            emit('D')
            emit(str(x))
        case _:
            raise TypeError(f'Unknown obj {x!r}')
```

## Sample runs

Here we show that the two problematic cases work as expected.

```
>>> dump_obj((10, 20))     # Tuple of integers
T
L
D
2
D
10
D
20

>>> class List(list):
...     pass
...
>>> dump_obj(List((30, 40)))   # List subclass
I
T
L
D
2
S
D
4
List
L
D
2
D
30
D
40
```